# kafka filtering messages vs tombstones

Tags: apache-kafka, transformation, apache-kafka-connect

I'm reading into the filtering of messages in Kafka and I've seen some examples that look interesting to me but I have a questions, which is not a code error I'm getting but is just to confirm my understanding.

If I read the code correctly for example the filter of the message just makes the record null

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Filter.java#L39

Is the record null not the same as saying the content is a tombstone record?
How will the further process be able to understand if this was a valid tombstone record or a simple message that was filtered (I can understand the message key will be different)

Mainly for systems that are interested in the tombstone I'm just wondering if filtering will not have un-desired consequences but maybe my understanding of the "null" being the same as tombstone is totally wrong.

I do understand (or I think I do) that there is a difference between `record.value() == null` or `record == null` but would this not cause a lot of null pointer exceptions in the rest of the transformation chain?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: for example a good guide on the filtering https://rmoff.net/2020/12/22/twelve-days-of-smt-day-11-predicate-and-filter/ but I did not fully get if my point is covered there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tombstone record has a non-null key, and null value *property*. You cannot get a key of a null Connect Record instance.

The transformation chain will ignore null records on subsequent transforms, therefore they are more "dropped" than filtered based on a particular attribute

Comment: thank you that was what I was looking for. basically my question was more do I need to modfiy all my transforms to ensure that they do nothing on "null"
something like "if record == null return record" for all of them

Comment: I think checking for null wouldn't hurt, but I also think it's assumed the incoming data for several of the existing connectors will not be null. And returning null to the framework will all get filtered out